# Error in webview.xml when creating Android application

Tags: android

In webview.xml, I see an error like this:

> Multiple annotations found at this line.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Please paste your webview.xml code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got same error. its spelling or invalid continuation of statement.Find any spelling mistake or spaces missing in your xml file